# Installation issue on Mac

Tags: javascript, macos, cypress

I am pretty new to Cypress, during installation, I was checking some other things on the computer, PLUS, I was not expecting Cypress would ask for access to location, photo, documents ... etc; thought maybe something else is asking, and went ahead and denied.

then I noticed Cypress was waiting for me to give access to those, and now I am unable to run the test.

can someone tell me how I can wipe out that part of my Mac's "memory", so that I can start over?

I tried to uninstall and re-install a few times, but this computer seems to be "holding grudges", not allowing me to fix the issue.

I'd really appreciate if someone could give me some hints on this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: try a Docker cypress instead?

Comment: Cypress would require you to give access to files for creating snapshots. Also, can you check if Cypress is installed as a global package or just inside your project?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about Mac, but Cypress installs binaries in a cache.

See this page [cypress cache [command]](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-cache-command) for various cache commands, possibly you can use `cypress cache clear` to start over.

Comment: Thank you Paolo. I was able to make it work. :)

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, create a new (empty) repository by creating a new folder and changing into that folder. If you [install via npm](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress), the version per repository will be downloaded, i.e. you start fresh in the new folder:

1. To create a node project in that folder execute `npm init -y`
2. To add Cypress execute `npm install cypress --save-dev`

Comment: Thank you Michael. I was finally able to make it work. It was partially due to some new changes came with Cypress 10, and I was expecting it to look like a reference I had for Cypress 9